# Can a continuous function exist under these conditions?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let (M,d) be a metric space. $A \subseteq M$ and closed. Further let $U \subseteq M$ a open subset and  $A \subseteq U$.

Does a continouos function $f: M \rightarrow [0,1]$ exist such that
$f(x)=1$ if $x \in A$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x \notin U$

I dont't know how to approach this.
Would be thankful for hints

Comment: This appears to be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma in the case of metric spaces (where the closed sets in question are $A$ and $M \setminus U$).

Comment: @Ian thank you!